# Properly handling Up navigation and activity recreation on low memory situation

Tags: android, navigation, activity-lifecycle

My app has 3 activities that are chained together with this direction A -> B -> C. Now that I have read the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) on how to handle the up navigation between activities, it does not work as expected in some cases. My slightly modified code when clicking on the Up button:

```
case android.R.id.home:
     Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
     if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, intent))
           TaskStackBuilder.create(this).addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent).startActivities();
     else {
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
           NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
     }
return true;
```

In normal situation it does work with the same behavior as pressing the Back button (parent activity does not get reloaded). However when I tried to create a low memory environment when I was at Activity C, I can go back to B (it got recreated), but I could not get to A from B, instead it went straight to my home screen. What I want is I can go back from B to A as from C to B.

I have the correct `android:parentActivityName` tag in all the activities so it is not the problem here. I even tried setting activity A `android:launchMode="singleTop"` but it did not work either. Anyone has the solution to this?

Comment: add some more code. May be you are finishing activity somewhere.

Comment: No I don't have any call lead to finishing activity A. As I said, in normal condition it works perfectly fine, issue only happens when the device runs low on memory.

Comment: why are you doing the way in the code you have posted?? You just simply does not finish your activity and when you will back press it will automatically go to last activity.

Comment: This is Up button we are talking about, not Back button. They are not the same.

Comment: what does this up button do infact. Can you clarify the difference??

Comment: You can read on the link I posted above. They are different functionality-wise.